# Parallel reading of input file with Parallel::Loops module

Tags: perl

I often come across a scenario where I need to parse a very large input file and then process the lines for final output. With many of these files it can take a while to process.

Since it's usually the same process, and usually I want to stored the processed data to a hash for the final manipulation, it seems that maybe something like [`Parallel::Loops`](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aLoops) would be helpful and speed the process up.

If I'm not thinking this through correctly, please let me know.

I've used `Parallel::Loops` before to process many files at a time with great results, but I can't figure out how to process many lines from one file as I don't know how to pass each line of the file in as a reference.

If I try to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Parallel::Loops;

my $procs = 12;
my $pl = Parallel::Loops->new($procs);

my %data;
$pl->share(\%data);

my $input_file = shift;
open( my $in_fh, "<", $input_file ) || die "Can't open the file for reading: $!";

$pl->while( <$in_fh>, sub {
    <some kind of munging and processing here>
});
```

I get the error:

```
Can't use string ("6334") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Parallel/Loops.pm line 518, <$in_fh> line 501.
```

I know that I need to pass a reference to the parallel object but I can't figure out how to make a reference to a `readline` element.

I also know that I can slurp the whole file in first and then pass an array reference of all of the lines, but for very large files that takes a lot of memory, and intuitively a lot more time as it technically needs to then read the file twice.

Is there a way to pass each line of a file into the `Parallel::Loops` object so that I can process many of the lines of a file at once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this as my laptop doesn't have `Parallel::Loops` installed and I have no consistent internet access.

However, from [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel%3a%3aLoops#while-loop), the `while` method clearly takes two subroutine reference for parameters and you are passing `<$in_fh>` as the first. The method probably coerces its parameters to scalars using a prototype, so that means you are passing a simple string where a subroutine reference is expected.

Because of my situation I am far from certain, but you may get a result from

```
$pl->while(
    sub {
      scalar <$in_fh>;
    },
    sub {
      # Process a line of data
    }
);
```

I hope this helps. I will investigate further when I get home on Friday.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  I have been combing the docs as well, and realized that I should be passing a sub reference.  I arrived at the same conclusion as you, but this doesn't quite work. I don't think this is a feasible strategy as the first sub is just a conditional to tell the loop(s) how long to run.  So, I run into a race condition checking there are more lines to read from the first sub and reading / processing lines in the second, resulting in a random number of lines read (and a host of uninitialized variable warnings).  I think maybe I need another approach.

Comment: @drmrgd: That makes sense; I'm sorry I missed it. It sounds like you need to chunk your input file so that the threads can operate on their own chunk. How big is your input file really? *"Very large"* doesn't help much! And how much free RAM does your system generally run with?

Comment: The answers to those questions vary quite a bit depending on the system and files I'm working with.  File size can range from maybe 1-10 million lines (maybe not too bad?), and usually I have at least 8GB of RAM to work with.  In the end I think I figured out how to use `Parallel::Loops` combined with `Tie::File` for this problem, but it's actually quite a bit slower than the standard single core method.  So, maybe this is not worth spending time trying to optimize further.

Comment: @drmrgd: 10M lines of, say, 100 characters is 100MB, which should be fine for one process with 8GB to spare: you could read the whole file and create worker threads to process it in chunks. I would recommend `Tie::File` except that the `tie` interface itself is *very* slow, and it is better to use `tell` and `seek` to do the same job without the `tie` overhead. It depends on the times you're seeing. If you have to get a 3-day run down inside 24 hours then go ahead and work on it, but if it's taking 30 minutes and you don't need the result before the afternoon then leave things as they are.